# array elements are pointing to the same object for no reason

Tags: python, arrays

I am solving a class project and I faced this problem (when I append a new object to the array it seems like all the elements are pointing at the same object)
here is my code

```
import os
from Process import Process

processes = []

# Read the file
file = open("file.txt","r")
# Read the lines
for line in file.readlines() :
    # split the line components
    process = line.split(";")
    global processes
    # append a new element to the array
    pr = Process(process[0], process[1], "Ready")
    # find how many elements in the line to loop through
    process_len = len(process)
    # loop through the line elements
    for element in range(2,process_len) :
        #  if it's a CPU
        if process[element].find("CPU") == 0:
            s = process[element].split(":")
            pr.add_cpu(s[1])
        #  if it's an IO
        elif process[element].find("IO") == 0:
            s = process[element].split(":")
            pr.add_io(s[1])
    #     End of elif
    processes.append(pr)
file.close()
print "-------------------------- \n";
for p in processes :
    print p.getcpu()
```

here is the file I'm reading from :

```
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35;IO:5;CPU:1
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;CPU:30;IO:11;CPU:35
1;500;CPU:20;IO:5;CPU:10;IO:15;
```

and here is the output :

```
-------------------------- 

['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']
['20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10', '20', '10', '30', '35', '1\n', '20', '10', '30', '20', '10', '30', '35\n', '20', '10']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think the problem is that I'm creating new references to the same object and I keep adding them to the array as new objects but I don't know how to make sure if that is the case or I'm wrong and if that is the case how can I solve this problem ?

Edit: 
Here is the process class :

```
class Process :

    pid = 0;
    pat = 0;
    wt  = 0;
    global ion;
    ion = 0;
    global cpun;
    cpun = 0;
    global pState;
    pState = "Ready";
    global pNature;
    pNature = "I\O bound";
    global turnAroundTime;
    turnAroundTime = 0;
    global cpu;
    cpu = []
    global io;
    io  = []

    # constructor
    def __init__(self,id,at,state) :
        pid = id;
        pat = at;
        pState = state;

    # define the process nature
    @staticmethod
    def nature() :
        global pNature;
        global ion;
        global cpun;
        if ion > cpun :
            pNature = "I\O bound";
        else :
            pNature = "CPU bound";

    # add new cpu
    @staticmethod
    def add_cpu(cp) :
       cpu.append(cp);
       global cpun;

       cpun = cpun + int(cp);

    # add new io
    @staticmethod
    def add_io(i) :
       io.append(i);
       global ion;
       ion = ion + int(i);

     # get the cpu array size
    @staticmethod
    def get_cpu_size() :
        return len(cpu);

        # get the IO array size
    @staticmethod
    def get_io_size() :
        return len(io)

    # returns the cpu array
    @staticmethod
    def getcpu():
        return cpu
```

Comment: @Keatinge I get the same output

Comment: I guarantee it's not for no reason. But you need to show the code for the Process class.

Comment: BTW, doing `global processes` in the global context is pointless. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt)

Comment: You're using `global` everywhere, so obviously the values are shared.

Comment: I'm confused by your class design - you are using `global` and `@staticmethod` for everything, meaning that nothing is actually encapsulated into the object - every object accesses the exact same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables of the class process were common to each instansiation of pr. So you were crushing the values every time.

```
import os

processes = []

class Process():
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, id, at, state):
        self.pid = id
        self.pat = at
        self.pState = state
        self.wt = 0
        self.ion = 0
        self.cpun = 0
        self.pNature = "I\O bound"
        self.turnAroundTime = 0
        self.cpu = []
        self.io = []

    # define the process nature
    def nature(self):
        if self.ion > self.cpun:
            self.pNature = "I\O bound"
        else:
            self.pNature = "CPU bound"

    # add new cpu
    def add_cpu(self, cp):
        self.cpu.append(cp)
        self.cpun = self.cpun + int(cp)

    # add new io
    def add_io(self, i):
        self.io.append(i)
        self.ion = self.ion + int(i)

    # get the cpu array size
    def get_cpu_size(self):
        return len(self.cpu)

    # get the IO array size
    def get_io_size(self):
        return len(self.io)

    # returns the cpu array
    def getcpu(self):
        return self.cpu


# Read the file
file = open("file.txt", "r")
# Read the lines
for line in file.readlines():
    # split the line components
    process = line.split(";")
    # append a new element to the array
    pr = Process(process[0], process[1], "Ready")
    # find how many elements in the line to loop through
    process_len = len(process)
    # loop through the line elements
    for element in range(2, process_len):
        #  if it's a CPU
        if process[element].find("CPU") == 0:
            s = process[element].split(":")
            pr.add_cpu(s[1])
        #  if it's an IO
        elif process[element].find("IO") == 0:
            s = process[element].split(":")
            pr.add_io(s[1])
    #     End of elif
    processes.append(pr)
file.close()
print("-------------------------- \n")
for p in processes:
    print(p.getcpu())
```

PS: Don't use **;** in Python. And try to use Pep8. It's a python style guide.

Comment: the functions are separate for each object , however I'll post the class

Comment: What do you expect as output ?